# Different methods of copying dicts and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, copy

In Python there are various ways to create a shallow copy of a `dict`: there's the `dict` constructor, the `dict.copy` method, and the function `copy` from the `copy` module:

```
>>> a = {'a':3, 'b': [1,2,3]}
>>> b = dict(a)
>>> c = a.copy()
>>> from copy import copy
>>> d = copy(a)
>>> a['a'] = 2
>>> a['b'].append(4)
>>> b
{'a': 3, 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
>>> c
{'a': 3, 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
>>> d
{'a': 3, 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
>>> a
{'a': 2, 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

From the above example, all these 3 methods seem to achieve the same result. Is there a difference in their functionality and should one of them be preferred over the others?

A similar question could be asked for lists, where we can use `l2 = list(l1)`, `l2 = l1.copy()`, `l2 = copy.copy(l1)` or `l2 = l1[:]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: they are functionally equivalent.

No differences between the functions are described in the documentation. Examining the source, each will use the same function (`dict_merge`) in many cases.

Looking at the source of the `copy` module, [`copy.copy`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/copy.py#LC66) calls `dict.copy` (as well as a few other type-specific copy methods, such as `list.copy`, for values of those types). Thus the only difference between `copy(d)` and `d.copy()` is that a variable must be known to have a `copy` method to use the latter.

The help doc for `dict(d)` notes:

> dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's (key, value) pairs

The constructor works on all mapping types, not just dicts. This won't cause functional differences, but could impact performance due to handling a more general case. However, examining the source shows the constructor calls [`dict_merge`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9304f9855852f8cc823534b954206181b933065e/Objects/dictobject.c#L2816) to handle copying the data, which handles `dict`s specially, so the underlying function can apply case-specific optimizations.

`dict.copy` calls [`PyDict_copy`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9304f9855852f8cc823534b954206181b933065e/Objects/dictobject.c#L3013), which handles a few special cases itself but calls `dict_merge` if none of those apply.

In summary: in terms of functionality, use any of them. If a value is known to have a `copy` method (e.g. it's known to be a `dict`), `d.copy()` will likely be the most performant option. If the exact type of a value isn't known but it's known to be a mapping type, use `copy.copy()` or `dict()`. If nothing is known about the type, use `copy.copy()`.

Copy operations on `list` should be similar, though using a slice (`l1[:]`) may not use the same underlying function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want any update occurring in the `dict` variable to happen to the other one you can use:

```
dictb=dicta
```

Any update to an iterable / compound object(e.g. a list) or a non-iterable element will happen to the other.

If you want the non-iterable element to stay intact, you can either copy the element-by-element the content of the `dict`, or use the method `copy()`

```
dictb= dicta.copy()
```

or

```
dictb=copy(dicta)
```

Finally, if you want neither to be updated in the copied `dict` use `deepcopy()`

```
from copy import deepcopy
dictb=deepcopy(dicta)
```

As for the speed `dicta.copy()` is the fastest, then `dict(dicta)`, then `copy(dicta)`